# Multiple SET - WHERE in the same UPDATE

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-update

I have a table in Bigquery in which I want to update several records, currently I do an UPDATE for each record:

```
UPDATE MY_DATASET.TABLE_ONE
SET fieldOne = 'data1', fieldTwo = 'data2'
WHERE fieldKey = 'key1' and fieldData in ('dataF1','dataF3')

UPDATE MY_DATASET.TABLE_ONE
SET fieldOne = 'data11', fieldTwo = 'data21'
WHERE fieldKey = 'key2' and fieldData = 'dataF2'
```

When making two UPDATEs on the same table, it is possible to make only one UPDATE but with several SET and WHERE? statements, that is, is it possible to join both UPDATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE .. WHEN..` expression. Consider below query.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE TABLE_ONE AS
SELECT 'key1' fieldKey, 'dataF1' fieldData, 'dummy1' fieldOne, 'dummy2' fieldTwo UNION ALL
SELECT 'key2' fieldKey, 'dataF2' fieldData, 'dummy1' fieldOne, 'dummy2' fieldTwo UNION ALL
SELECT 'key3' fieldKey, 'dataF3' fieldData, 'dummy1' fieldOne, 'dummy2' fieldTwo;

UPDATE TABLE_ONE
SET fieldOne = CASE (fieldKey, fieldData) WHEN ('key1', 'dataF1') THEN 'data1' ELSE 'data11' END,
    fieldTwo = CASE (fieldKey, fieldData) WHEN ('key1', 'dataF1') THEN 'data2' ELSE 'data21' END
WHERE (fieldKey, fieldData) IN (('key1', 'dataF1'), ('key2', 'dataF2'));

SELECT * FROM TABLE_ONE;
```

- [tuple syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#tuple_syntax) can be used with STRUCT comparison for comparison expressions using multi-part keys, e.g. in a WHERE clause:

  ```sql
  WHERE (Key1,Key2) IN ( (12,34), (56,78) )
  ```

**Query results**

[image]

**Update:** you can think *tuple syntax* as kind of syntatic sugar. If you have more complicated conditions, you can write them down as they are both in `WHERE` and `CASE` conditions.

```sql
UPDATE TABLE_ONE
SET fieldOne = CASE WHEN fieldKey = 'key1' and fieldData in ('dataF1','dataF3') THEN 'data1' ELSE 'data11' END,
    fieldTwo = CASE WHEN fieldKey = 'key2' and fieldData = 'dataF2' THEN 'data2' ELSE 'data21' END
WHERE (fieldKey = 'key1' and fieldData in ('dataF1','dataF3'))
   OR (fieldKey = 'key2' and fieldData = 'dataF2');
```

Comment: How can I do it in case I have more than one condition in the WHERE?. I have updated the question

Comment: @mikestr, you can use *tuple syntax* in this case. check the updated answer.

Comment: In the CASE you are using only fieldKey, since I can include fieldKey and fieldData within the same CASE, I need all the conditions to match for each SET CASE

Comment: @mikestr, same tuple syntax can be used in `CASE..WHEN..` . I've updated answer.

Comment: ok that's how it works. I have updated the question with another question that I am testing, how can I put a condition in the WHEN to include the data from the WHEN ... IN??. I have updated the question

Comment: @mikestr, kindly check my updated answer for above question.